# `byobu` window with `sudo su -`

Tags: sudo, tmux, byobu

Sorry for the [cross-posting](https://askubuntu.com/q/1130334/698199) across the fora. I am not sure if my original post was in the correct forum.

---

I am aware that what I would like to do is not safe...

I would like to open a window in my byobu session with root prompt. (i.e. with `sudo su -`.) Once I get the root prompt, I would like to execute my script (`/root/command.sh`)(as root) and then give me the root prompt again.

I can achieve the first part by putting the following line in my `window.tmux`:

```
new-window -n 'root' sudo su -;
```

Using `send-keys`, I can get the root prompt. However it is not executing the command.

```
new-window -n root sudo su -;
send-keys mypassword C-m;
send-keys source ~/command.sh C-m;
```

P.S.

For some reasons it is not possible to use `visudo` on these commands.

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` and `su` together. `sudo bash`, or `sudo -i`  will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Su will flush the tty input buffer before waiting for the password, so you will need a delay before the send-keys or the password (which is likely to already be in the buffer by then) will be gone. Try adding "run 'sleep 1'" before the first send-keys.

Comment: it seems `run 'sleep 1'` command needs running tmux server. If I include this line in my `tmux.conf` then I am get the following error:
> no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

Comment: How do you expect new-window and send-keys to work without a running tmux server?

Comment: I mean `run` command doesnt seems to be acceptable in `windows.tmux`. The first list in the file is (before the lines mentioned in the post):
`new-session -AD -s 'root';`
However when I add
`run-shell 'sleep 5';` before the first `send-keys`, it throws an error.

Comment: This works fine for me: nicholas@macbook-air:~$ cat x
new-window -n root cat;
run "sleep 1";
send-keys abc;
send-keys def;
nicholas@macbook-air:~$ tmux -Ltest new\; source x

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me too, however only if I `source` the file. The default way (using `windows.tmux`) is still a no-go for me.